# Symbol Not Found On OnActionExpandListener

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, xamarin, android-support-library

I'm adding v4 support to my android application supporting gingerbread and up.  I added ActionBarSherlock, which references Xamarin.Android.Support.v4.  There is also a reference to Mono.Android.Support.v4 too.  I also added the android-support-v4.jar file to the SupportLib folder, and set the Build Action to AndroidJavaLibrary.  However, I'm getting an error I can't get past, which is:

```
/obj/Debug/android/src/mono/android/support/v4/view/MenuItemCompat_OnActionExpandListenerImplementor.java(41,41): Error:  cannot find symbol
    symbol  : class OnActionExpandListener
    location: class android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat
            android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener
```

Why is this error happening?  How can it be resolved?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't reference both `Xamarin.Android.Support.V4` and `Mono.Android.Support.V4`.

I'd suggest referencing just `Xamarin.Android.Support.V4` as it is the updated binding to the Android Support Library v4. Remove `Mono.Android.Support.V4` and `android-support-v4.jar`.

Comment: Many thanks!  I assume Mono.Android.Support.V4 and the support JAR was an older approach, and the Xamarin.Android.Support.V4 DLL is the new approach to v4 support.

Comment: Thank you @Tom Opgenorth - fixed my issue! :)

Comment: I was still getting this error even after removing Mono.Android.Support.v4, had to Clean the project to get it to build. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same problem using Xamarin studio after switching my solution to work with Xamarin Forms instead of native android.

What did the trick for me and solved it was to clean my project and rebuild
(Build --> Clean All)
Good luck!